# Test class for a controller having wrapper class,code coverage appears Zero

Tags: unit-test, controller, wrapper-class

Can any one help me out with test class code coverage .I have written a test class for a controller having wrapper class,but the code covearage in the test class appears Zero and the overall code coverage is 79%.

**I have few doubts :**

1)if we have 'n'no of if conditions in a controller ,then we need to call 'n' no of if conditions with 'n' of methods;

2)if we have '2'wrapper class in a controller ,then we need to call 2 wrapper class with their if conditions with 'n' of methods;

**I keep getting different types of Error while running the test :**

1)`System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

Line is :`Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2(Name='NONDIE');`

2)When i add (seealldata=true) for @istest annotation , the test class get executes ,if i dont give (seealldata=true) for @istest annotation , the test class does not get executed.

**Test Class :**

```
@istest

Public class  TestInvoiceController{

static Testmethod void Invoicemethodtest(){

 test.startTest();

 Date closeDt = Date.Today();

 //String standardPriceBookId = '';

// set up Account and Verify that the results are as expected.

Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'icrm test acc';
insert a;

//// set up opportunity and Verify that the results are as expected.

opportunity op = new opportunity(Name='test DIE 4/6/2015' ,  AccountId= a.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt, Shipment_Info__c='test',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line1__c='Road No 37',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line2__c='Jubilee Hills',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line3__c='Land Mark Neerus',
                                   Shipping_City__c='Hyd',
                                   Shipping_State_Province__c='TS',
                                   Shipping_Zipcode__c='500081',
                                   Shipping_Country__c ='India',
                                   Bill_of_Lading__c='This is waybill1 this is waybill 2 waybill3 -34958309458 waybill - 44570375');

  insert op;
  Opportunity opp = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :op.Id];
System.assertEquals('test DIE 4/6/2015', opp.Name);



  // set up product and Verify that the results are as expected.

  Product2 pro = new Product2(Product_Line__c='DIE',Name='BXCD',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXCD24',isActive=true);
  insert pro;
  Product2 p2ex = [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :pro.Id];
   System.assertEquals('BXCD', p2ex.Name);

   // set up pricebook and Verify that the results are as expected.

  Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2(Name='DIE');
 insert pb2;
  PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
//standardPriceBookId = pb2Standard.Id;

   // set up pricebookentry and Verify that the results are as expected.

PricebookEntry pbe =new PricebookEntry(unitprice=0.01,Product2Id=pro.Id,Pricebook2Id=pb2Standard.Id,isActive=true,UseStandardPrice = false
);
 insert pbe;
 PricebookEntry pbeex = [SELECT Pricebook2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id = :pbe.Id];
//System.assertEquals(pb2Standard, pbeex.Pricebook2Id);

  // set up opportunitylineitem and Verify that the results are as expected.

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem= new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=op.Id,UnitPrice=0.01,PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id);
 insert OPplineitem;

  test.stopTest();

  InvoiceController ic = new InvoiceController();
  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('opId',op.id);


  }

 static Testmethod void Invoicemethodtest1(){
 test.startTest();

 Date closeDt = Date.Today();

 //String standardPriceBookId = '';

  // set up account and Verify that the results are as expected.

 Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'icrm test acc';
insert a;

/// set up opportunity and Verify that the results are as expected.

opportunity op = new opportunity(Name='test NonDIE 4/6/2015' , AccountId= a.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt,Shipment_Info__c='test',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line1__c='Road No 37',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line2__c='Jubilee Hills',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line3__c='Land Mark Neerus',
                                   Shipping_City__c='Hyd',
                                   Shipping_State_Province__c='TS',
                                   Shipping_Zipcode__c='500081',
                                   Shipping_Country__c ='India' , 
                                   Bill_of_Lading__c='This is waybill1 this is waybill 2 waybill3 -34958309458 waybill - 44570375');

  insert op;
  Opportunity opp = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :op.Id];
System.assertEquals('test NonDIE 4/6/2015', opp.Name);

  // set up product and Verify that the results are as expected.
  Product2 pro = new Product2(Product_Line__c='NONDIE',Name='BXRC',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXRC27',isActive=true);
  insert pro;
  Product2 p2ex = [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :pro.Id];
System.assertEquals('BXRC', p2ex.Name);


  // set up pricebook and Verify that the results are as expected.
  Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2(Name='NONDIE');
  insert pb2; 
  PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
 // standardPriceBookId = pb2Standard.Id;
  // set up pricebookentry and Verify that the results are as expected.
  PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(unitprice=1,Product2Id=pro.Id,isActive=true,Pricebook2Id=pb2Standard.Id,UseStandardPrice = false
);
   insert pbe;
  PricebookEntry pbeex = [SELECT Pricebook2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id = :pbe.Id];
//System.assertEquals(pb2Standard, pbeex.Pricebook2Id); 

 // set up opportunitylineitem and Verify that the results are as expected.

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem= new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=op.Id,UnitPrice=1,PriceBookEntryId=pbe.id );

  insert OPplineitem;
  OpportunityLineItem oliex = [SELECT PriceBookEntryId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :OPplineitem.Id];
System.assertEquals(pbe.Id, oliex.PriceBookEntryId); 

  test.stopTest();

  InvoiceController ic = new InvoiceController();

  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('opId',op.id);

     }                        
  }
```

**Controller :**

```
public with sharing class InvoiceController {
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList {get;set;}
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList1 {get;set;} 
           public list<string> address{get;set;}
           public string address1{get;set;}
           public string address2{get;set;}
           public string address3{get;set;}
           public string address4{get;set;}
           public string address5{get;set;}
           public string address6{get;set;}
           public string address7{get;set;}
           public String showaddressonVf{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}


   //Added by sumit
               List<String> stringList ;
               public String all{get;set;}
           //------------
   public InvoiceController(){
   list<opportunity> op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c
   from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
    //opportunity op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
       //---------------------Added by sumit----------------------
       stringList= new List<String>(); 
       if(op.size()>0)
       if(op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=NULL && op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=''){
           List<String> stringList=(op[0].Shipment_Info__c).split(',');
               for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
               }

           all=all.remove('null');      
        }
      //------------------------------------------------------------
   }
       public Id OppId{get;set;}



       public InvoiceController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
       oppId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
   }


          public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList (){
                              wrapperClass tempObj;
               tempObj = new wrapperClass();

               List<wrapperClass> aReList = new List<wrapperClass>(); 
           List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           List<opportunity> Opp1=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid];
           //Opportunity opp1=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           //Opportunity Opp=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid ];
                          List<OpportunityLineItem> OPplineitem= [SELECT OpportunityId,Quantity,PricebookEntry.Product2.Name,Sys_total_Amount__c,LN__c,Extension__c,ListPrice
                          ,Pick__c,Schedule_Ship_date__c,Bin_Item_Code__c ,PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c,OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Subtotal__c,OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c,
                           OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Pick_Total__c,Newextension__c,unit_price__c ,ItemNumber__c,product_code__c FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:oppId]; 
                          system.debug('HHHHHHHHHH'+OPplineitem.size());

                       for(integer i=0; i < OPplineitem.size(); i++)
                       {
                     tempObj = new wrapperClass();
                     tempObj.productname= OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
                     tempObj.BinItemCode=OPplineitem[i].Bin_Item_Code__c;
                     tempObj.quantity=OPplineitem[i].Quantity;
                     tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                     tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c ;
                     tempObj.totalamount=OPplineitem[i].Sys_total_Amount__c;
                     tempObj.Subtotal =OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Subtotal__c;
                     tempObj.NonPickTotal=OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c;
                     tempObj.PickTotal=OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Pick_Total__c;
                     tempObj.Newextension=OPplineitem[i].Newextension__c;
                     tempObj.Unitprice=OPplineitem[i].unit_price__c;
                     tempObj.ItemNumber=OPplineitem[i].ItemNumber__c;
                     tempObj.productcode=OPplineitem[i].product_code__c;
                     tempobj.LineNumber=OPplineitem[i].LN__c;
                     tempobj.Pick= OPplineitem[i].Pick__c;
                     tempobj.ScheduledShipDate = Opplineitem[i].schedule_ship_date__c;

                     if(tempobj!=null){
                        aReList.add(tempObj);
                     }
                    }

           return aReList;
 }

 public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList1 (){
           wrapperClass tempObj1 ; 
           List<wrapperClass> aReList1 = new List<wrapperClass>();
                   List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId,Shipment_Info__c,
                    Shipping_Address_Line1__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line2__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line3__c,
                        Shipping_City__c,
                        Shipping_State_Province__c,
                        Shipping_Zipcode__c,
                        Shipping_Country__c  
                        from Opportunity where id=:oppid];
           for(integer i=0; i < opp.size(); i++)
           {
             tempObj1 = new wrapperClass();
             tempObj1.billingAddress= opp[i].Shipment_Info__c;
                               }
             aReList1.add(tempObj1);        



             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line1__c + '<br/>';
             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c + '<br/>';
             } 

             if(opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + '<br/>';
             }  

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';
             }

      return aReList1;  
   }
           public class wrapperClass{
          // public String Item{get;private set;}
           public String productname{get; set;}
           public String BinItemCode{get;set;}
           public Decimal Quantity{get;set;}
           public Decimal totalamount{get;set;}
           public Decimal Subtotal{get;set;}
           public Decimal NonPickTotal{get;set;} 
           public Decimal PickTotal{get;set;}                             
           public Decimal unitprice{get;set;}
           public Decimal Newextension{get;set;}
           public String ItemNumber{get;set;}
           public date todaysdate{get;set;}
           public decimal extension{get;set;}
           public string LineNumber{get;set;}
           public string productcode{get;set;}
           public string billingAddress{get;set;}
           public string splittedaddress{get;set;}
           public string productline{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
           public boolean Pick{get;set;}
           public date ScheduledShipDate{get;set;}
           public wrapperClass(){}                
       }
 }
```

I shall really appreciate your help.

Comment: First observation: you do things like:

insert op;
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :op.Id];

However, after such an insert, op.Id does not have a value. It will be null. You have to do another SELECT to retrieve the Id value. Fix that first.

Comment: @Sander de Jong:I have removed the query ,but still facing the error.Any help very much appreciated.